# Searching with a 1D car?

Tags: integers, random, discrete-optimization, programming, searching

Consider the task of programming a 1D car starting on point $0$.
The car drives 1 km / min ( to both left and right).

The task is to find a coin at an unknown integer distance $x$ (in km) from the starting point $0$.

In the most efficient way ofcourse !!

Example

The coin is at 3.
The car is programmed to drive to 7 first , then -9.

The car starts going to 7 but stops when he arrives at 3 because the coin is detected.

3 km hence 3 min. Optimal result.

Second example

Coin at - 4.

Car is programmed

Go to 1, -1 , 2 , -2 , 3 , -3 , 4 , -4 ,  ...

Coin is found at -4 but the result is very poor !!

So the question is

What is the best strategy or way to program the car ??

Is The best way even unique ?

Im talking best on average because depending on the position of the coin luck might help ofcourse.

Going forward all the time is most successful if $x$ is positive ofcourse. But fails 50 % of the time !!

It needs to work all the time !!

This appeared as a simple task to me.

But I started getting doubts.

Should we program like

Go to 1,-2,4,-8,16,... ??
Or more like Fibonacci ?

Or maybe triangular numbers ?

And how to make this mathematically formal ?

Also , what kind of math is this ??
Is this computer science or not ?

Not sure about the tags.

Comment: Do we have any idea as to what distribution the coin is placed via?  Recall that there is no such thing as a uniform distribution over a countably infinite set.

Comment: I think the problem is too hard to tackle in general. As @JMoravitz comment suggests, the answer depends heavily on the distribution of the coin placement.

Comment: Yes I know. @JMoravitz

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156077/searching-for-a-point-on-the-real-line?rq=1 analogous to the case where the coin is dropped according to a standard normal distribution.